# Infinite threaded function in class constructor

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I have a class that runs an infinite loop using threads to populate a thread-safe queue:

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
import time


class factory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = True
        self.q = Queue()
        t = Thread(target=self.count_indefinitely)
        t.start()
        time.sleep(3)
        print self.q.qsize()

    def count_indefinitely(self):
        i = 0
        while self.running:
            i += 1
            self.q.put(i)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = factory()
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'Hello!'
    f.running = False
```

The code reaches the part where I need to print out the size of the queue.  However, I can't get it to print "hello" in the main function.  How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: What is `time.wait`? I can't find the docs for it. Is that causing it to crash?

Comment: Sorry, mean't to use time.sleep(2).  Changed it.

Comment: Your code works fine. I just tested it. Remove the `sleep`s, and add a `print` that runs after the loop exits. You should see "hello" print before the loop finishes.

Comment: Hmm, I see.  Thank you for the help!